# How can I stop Apache starting every time I start Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

In previous Ubuntu Desktop versions, I remember a "Services" GUI app which enabled me to select / deselect from a list of service type software like Apache web server and thus tell the system whether to load at start up or not.  I can't find this in 9.10 - what's the correct way to stop Apache loading every time I sign in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it via the command line: `update-rc.d apache2 remove`

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice little curses gui app for modifying run levels.

sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf

If you don't know what something does, don't mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: Ubuntu removed the 'Services' option from Karmic. So you remembered correctly.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-tools/+bug/433701